# convert UNIX timestamp to non-local time in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I figured out how to UNIX time to local time, but I can't figure how to convert to a different time zone (Central time with daylight saving). Can somebody help?

Comment: A little googling would have found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706808/changing-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-different-timezone) for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `time.tzset`. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) provides some good examples setting also the `TZ` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks! Tried and bumped into one issue... when I set os.environ['TZ'] to 'EST', it doesn't do daylight saving, but when I set os.environ['TZ] to 'CST6CDT, it does (and it should in the date I am looking at).... I am a little confused about this...

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/), a timezone definition package for Python.  After you installed and imported timezon from pytz, you need to make your local datetime object timezone aware (e.g. for UTC):

```
datetime_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
```

after that you can convert this aware datetime object to another timezone:

```
datetime_obj.astimezone(timezone('CST'))
```